# Не работает Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Имеется код

```
$html = file_get_html('https://www.sravni.ru/bank/sberbank-rossii/novosti');
        foreach ($html->find('div.article-preview-text-container a') as $e) {
            $json = file_get_contents('https://www.sravni.ru' . $e->href);
            preg_match('#<h1 class="heading-big heading-big--small">(.+?)</h1>#si', $json, $name);
            preg_match('#<div class="article-content">(.+?)</div>#si', $json, $text);
            preg_match('#<div class="article-info-date">(.+?)</div>#si', $json, $date);
        }
        var_dump($html);
```

Выдает ошибку **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on bool in

Что делаю не так?

Comment: очевидно, `file_get_html` вернул вам `false`

Comment: @teran, почему так произошло?

Comment: наверное, потому что запрос по этой ссылке возвращает 301 редирект

Comment: @teran, добавил слеш в конце ссылки. Ошибка та же.

Comment: следование редиректам добавьте в опции

Comment: Написал при помощи phpQuery.